# Parameter from the path includes query string in Sinatra. Is that correct?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, passenger

I am running a Sinatra app under Passenger. I have an action which looks roughly like this:

```
get '/pic/:id' do
  # do stuff ...
  canonical_image_url = "/img/%d.jpg" % params[:id]
end
```

However I see my app is failing with the following exception
`ArgumentError (invalid value for Integer(): "22?fill=width&width=512&sig=173798632b6ce659234a34c05324196c92b9a8ef")`

which means that somehow the QS parameters are not being extracted from the path. Is this some kind of a weird escaping problem? (that some part of my app requests with a double-encoded query string) or is this a known problem? Or is it designed that way and path-params and QS params cannot be used at the same time?

Comment: Are you sure the URL is a valid URL with properly formatted query string to begin with? Sinatra has no problems with URLs with attached query strings. They work just as expected. I.e. `example.com/pic/123?foo=111&bar=222` should hit your `get` method without any problems. Query strings in quotes are not valid URLs for any web server.

Comment: What URL is being requested? Look at your server logs or use a client-side browser inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way to write this (which will probably not help solve your problem, but is too long for a comment):

```
get '/pic/:id' do |id|
  # do stuff ...
  canonical_image_url = "/img/%d.jpg" % id
end
```

Comment: I will accept this answer since this problem only happens intermittently, and I think it's server dependent (might be a Passenger issue). If/when I get more information I will try to write up what and where.